# How do I extract index 0 of each list with Python?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have the following list named "rows":

```
[['1', 'Peter', 'Cookies'], ['2', 'Sarah', 'Chocolate'], ['3', 'Daria', 'Lollies']]
```

I'm trying to store the elements at index 0 within each list in a variable called ID with set comprehension but am struggling.

I've tried the following:

```
ID = {[row[0] for row in rows]}
```

but get the error:

> unhashable type list

I need to find a solution by using list comprehension.

Comment: you are almost there, replace the `{}` with `[]` like so: `[[row[0] for row in rows]]`

Comment: "with set comprehension" .... "need to find a solution by using list comprehension" - which one is it?

Comment: If you want set comprehension, remove the brackets. If you want list comprehension, remove the braces !

Comment: Hey! I got rid of the [] and did {row[0] for row in rows} which worked thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

THe error : unhashable type list is because you are trying to use a list as a key in a dictionary.
Try this to get the first element of each list.

```
ID = [row[0] for row in rows] 
# ['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: Not as a key in a dictionary, just as an element in a set. Both require hashing but not quite the same

Comment: Cheers, that worked. I just used the {} instead of []

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
import numpy as np
rows = [['1', 'Peter', 'Cookies'], ['2', 'Sarah', 'Chocolate'], ['3', 'Daria', 'Lollies']]
ID = [rows[row][0] for row in range(len(rows))]
ID
```

Output:

`['1', '2', '3']`